# How can I call some batch script if ROBOCOPY recognizes the file it is copying is identical to the destination file?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm using ROBOCOPY to copy a file from some source to a destination once a month. In a perfect world the folks responsible for the source file will be updating it on time before my copy job runs. But just in case they don't and I happen to pull over an identical file (because the source hasn't been updated since the last time my job ran) I would like to be able to call some more batch scripting I have written that will send out a warning email to my team.

I don't want this to terminate the copy, I would still like the copy to execute. Any ideas how I can do this? I've been looking at the ROBOCOPY documentation, but a solution doesn't seem apparent to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Start by posting what you have so far (presumably a bat file that launches RoboCopy). We will likely suggest that you perform this check prior to launching RoboCopy.

Answer (score 1):

If you could `robocopy sourcedir destdir individual.src` by itself, then its exit code will be 0 if the file already exists in the destination and is identical to the source.  An odd numbered errorlevel indicates that files were copied.  See [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) for more details on `robocopy`'s exit codes.

Be advised that if the file contents are the same but the timestamps are different, `robocopy` will still perform the copy, and therefore, exit non-zero.  However, by default, `robocopy` copies timestamps, so that may not be a problem.  If the destination file still has last month's timestamp, and the source hasn't been updated in a month, then they should still be identical.

With all that in mind, you can use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) to fire off the email if `robocopy` exits 0.

```js
robocopy sourcedir destdir individual.src && send_email.bat
```

---

If you can't depend on the timestamp as immutable, use `fc` to compare the source file and destination file.  [fc documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html).  You can still use conditional execution the same way.  If the file contents are identical, `fc` exits zero.

```js
>NUL fc sourcefile destfile && (

    rem // Files have the same contents
    send_email.bat

) || (

    rem // Source has been changed
    robocopy srcdir destdir file.src
)
```

Answer (score 0):

List all unchanged files *prior* to copying:

```
robocopy s:\ource d:\est /L /xc /xn /xx /is /ndl /ns /njh /njs /log:"%temp%\unchanged.txt" /tee
```

Then proceed with normal copy:

```
robocopy s:\ource d:\est
```

And send "%temp%\unchanged.txt" to whom it may concern.

Breakdown of the first command:

- `/L` - list-only mode, doesn't copy anything
- `/xc /xn /xx` - excludes changed, newer, extra files
- `/is` - includes same files
- `/ndl /ns /njh /njs` - removes extra info from the log, only lists the file names and the word "same" (you can hide it with `/nc`).
- `/log:"%temp%\unchanged.txt" /tee` - logs to the file and on the screen